# Merge two arrays of objects in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have an array of objects with unique IDs:

```
[{id: 1, score: 33}, {id: 23, score: 50}, {id:512, score: 27}, ...]
```

I also have an array of User records with matching IDs. The user records have "name" but not "score":

```
[{id: 1, name: "Jon"}, {id: 23, name: "Tom"}, {id: 512, name: "Joey"}, ...]
```

How can I create a single array with each id, name, and score?

```
[{id: 1, name: "Jon", score: 33}, {id: 23, name: "Tom", score: 50}, {id: 512, name: "Joey", score: 27}, ...]
```

I tried `merge`, `combine`, `filter`, etc but haven't found the Ruby function to accomplish this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that in `users` there is **always** record with corresponding `:id` from `scores`:

```
scores = [{id: 1, score: 33}, {id: 23, score: 50}, {id:512, score: 27}]
users  = [{id: 1, name: "Jon"}, {id: 23, name: "Tom"}, {id: 512, name: "Joey"}]

scores = scores.map { |score| score.merge(users.find { |user| user[:id] == score[:id] }) }
# => [{:id=>1, :score=>33, :name=>"Jon"}, {:id=>23, :score=>50, :name=>"Tom"}, {:id=>512, :score=>27, :name=>"Joey"}]
```

Hope that puts you in proper direction!

Comment: Interesting - thanks Pawel! Do you also know a function that lets me find just the matching object from scores given an ID?

Comment: Actually, this is what [`find`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) (from `Enumerable` module, which is included in [`Array`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html)) does. You should go with: `scores.find { |element| element[:id] == 123 }`. Check documentation for more examples. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can use an intermediate Hash.

```
hsh = Hash[ a1.map {|h| [h[:id], h[:score]]} ]
# => {1=>33, 23=>50, 512=>27}
a2.map {|h| h[:score] = hsh[h[:id]]; h}
# => [{:id=>1, :name=>"Jon", :score=>33}, {:id=>23, :name=>"Tom", :score=>50}, {:id=>512, :name=>"Joey", :score=>27}]
```

Comment: I like your solution, but would prefer `a2.each_with_object({}) { |g,h| h.update(g[id] => g) }`, as it doesn't mutate `a2` and IMO it reads better.

Answer (score 1):

If, as in the example, `scores[i][:id] = users[i][:id]` for all `i`, and you are using v1.9+ (where key insertion order is maintained), you could write:

```
scores.zip(users).each_with_object({}) do |(sh,uh),h|
   h.update(sh).update(uh)
end
```

Would I use this? Would you?